# How to put more than one image into an observable notebook cell?

Tags: javascript

I have several images attached to an observable notebook. I'd like to show them all in a cell because the user can toggle through them with a dropdown select. Using an HTML cell, I have:

```
<style>
  figure.small-example-img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px; 
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<figure class="small-example-img">
  <img src=`${await FileAttachment('Side.PNG').url()}` />
  <figcaption>Side: method one</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="small-example-img">
  <img src=`${img_urls.houseurl}` />
  <figcaption>house: method 2</figcaption>
</figure>
...and so on
```

In the first, I call the img url explicitly, and in the second I make a variable earlier to hold it. Both ways I end up with:

```
<figure class="small-example-img">
  <img src="\`https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/24_rest_of_url_7a9\`">
  <figcaption>Side</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If I put the URL directly into the `src` then it works fine.

What is the correct way to template this url into the html?

I suspect it has something to do with strange interpretation of the backticks?

---

There's an example file for this topic [here](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/html-in-markdown) but it doesn't have an image example

Answer (score 0):

Observable does seem to treat backticks as a special thing. If you take them out it seems to work just fine.

```
<figure class="small-example-img">
  <img src="${await FileAttachment('Side.PNG').url()}" />
  <figcaption>Side: method one</figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is one of those *it works, but I don't know why* answers, so if anyone knows the details, I'd love to know too!